# Blazor - UI not updating whilst task executing

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

Using Blazor WebAssembly, along with the MudBlazor components.

I have a `List<SomeClass>` and a [MudTable](https://mudblazor.com/components/table) that is bound to it.

I have the following button:

```
<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="@(async () => await MyMethodAsync())">
    <MudText Class="ms-2">Run MyMethod</MudText>
</MudButton>
```

Which calls the following method:

```
private async Task MyMethodAsync()
{ ... }
```

What this method does is to have a loop in which it makes an awaited HTTP call and updates the above mentioned list (which is bound to the table).

So, pseudo code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  HttpResponseMessage m = await Http.PostAsync(endpoint, data[i], _token);
  if (m.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    string response = await serverResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    _myListBoundToTable.AddRange(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<SomeClass>>(response);
  }
}
```

So....when this method has completed then the MudTable makes itself visibie with all the lovely data.

What I'd really like is that everytime I add data to the list within the loop then the MudTable rebinds and updates itself, so that the user may start viewing the data without having to wait for all the data to have been loaded.

Comment: I think your table is _myListBoundToTable, it is? So, you have to load all the table on a temp table and then copy when the loading is finished. Also I want to remark that the "await" inside a loop is serialized, I mean that you are doing one call each time. You need to use Parallel.ForEachAsync or Task.WhenAll

Comment: Clarify where `serverResponse` comes from.

Comment: How quickly does each loop take?  Henk's answer below will update every loop, but the re-render takes time.  Do you update every loop or every 10 loops?  You could get really cute and build in de-bouncer so say you only update every second or how long a loop takes whichever is the longer.  I'll add some code that demos such a de-bouncer if you want to look at that.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their comments. My pseudo code showed a single awaited call, it actually makes 10 calls per iteration and then those Tasks are awaited with a Task.WhenAll(...).  I also have a delay to throttle my calls and then execute the next loop.  I implemented @HH's suggestion of using StateHasChanged() which works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OnClick is an EventCallback, meaning the screen updates are normally handled automatically.

Conceptually, there is a StatehasChanged() call *before* and *after* the handling. You get up to 2 screen updates for free. But you have `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)` so you are missing 98 updates in the middle.

```
  if (m.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
     ... // as before
     StateHasChanged();  // add this
  }
```